# Cannot handle Ctrl + S in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I'm coding a text editor for part of my winforms application. It has the usual Bold, Underline, Strikeout, Italic toolbar buttons. For reasons of accessibility and workflow efficiency I want to add shortcuts as well, however.

Here's the  relevant code:

```
private void TextInput_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Control)
    {
        switch(e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.B: ChangeFontStyle('B');
            break;
            case Keys.I: e.SuppressKeypress = true; 
            ChangeFontStyle('I');
            break;
            // ... the others (U and S) look like the one for B, with the matching letters... 
        }
        }
    }
}

private voide ChangeFontStyle(char targetStyle)
{
    switch(targetStyle)
    {
        case 'B': 
        if(TextInput.Selectionfont.Bold)
        { 
            TextInput.SelectionFont = new Font(TextInput.Selectionfont, TextInput.Selectionfont.Style ^ FontStyle.Bold);

        }
        else
        {
           TextInput.SelectionFont = new Font(TextInput.Selectionfont, TextInput.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
        }
    }
}
```

The others look like this, too, just with italic, underline and strikeout respectively. For three of them itorks (though if I don't " `e.SuppressKeyPress` on ctrl-I, an indent gets set on top of font turning italic). Just strikeout doesn't work with ctrl-S. With ctrl-shift-S it works, and the `case 'S'` block never executes, so ctrl-S must somehow get caught somewhere and used for something else. But I definitely don't use it elsewhere. Suggestions?

Comment: Is your application standalone or is it embedded as a plugin or something in another application?

Comment: Standalone. I'll have to check later whether my screenreader snatches ctrl-S, but it's unlikely.

Comment: Maybe you could use spy++ (spyxx.exe) and watch the messages (events) of the form and get an idea what's going on.

Comment: Ctrl + S is usually used for saving in many applications. It might get catched by the `PreviewKeyDown` event, maybe you can check it out

Comment: @MartinVerjans PreviewKeyDown is WPF, isn't it?

Comment: Do you have a `MenuStrip` having a save menu item?

Comment: ...or the main window is intercepting it (save) ...

Comment: @SvenBardos Winforms also, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: First of all, thank you for all the suggestions!! And indeed! I have a MenuStrip with a save Menu Item which got automatically created. I'll check whether it uses the ctrl-S shortcut. That's probably our culprit. @Reza Aghaei put this in an answer so I can accept and upvote it.

Comment: Oops. @RezaAghaei - that's the tag formatting. Sorry, still learning.

Comment: @MartinVerjans Thanks for the link. Wasn't aware of this :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a `MenuStrip` on the form including a menu item with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> as `ShortcutKey`, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> will be consumed by menu item and your control will not receive the key combination.

`KeyDown` event of `RichTextBox` is too late for handling shortcut keys and `MenuStrip` or parent controls may consume the key combination in their `ProcessCmdKey`.

To handle shortcut keys for `RichTextBox`, use one of the following options:

- Have a `MenuStrip` including a `ToolStripMenuItem` assigned with the shortcut key to its `ShortcutKeys` propert, then handling `Click` event of the menu item:

  ```
  private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Handled by Save Menu");
  }
  ```
- Override `ProcessCmdKey` method of the `Form`:

  ```
  protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
  {
      if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.S))
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Handled by Form");
          return true;
      }
      return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
  }
  ```
- The last option is using `PreviewKeyDown` event of the `RichTextBox`:

  ```
  private void richTextBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.S))
      {
          e.IsInputKey = true;
          BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
              MessageBox.Show("Handled by RichTextBox");
          }));
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Awesome!! Yes, I inserted the default items in a MenuStrip - and was unaware the default save item has ctrl-s attached already. Thanks for giving me all these workarounds - I'll definitely pick one of these.

Comment: This is brilliant! The ProcessCmdKey override worked like a charm. I had the same problem with the Ctrl+V keys and a ToolStrip in the form that was also intercepting the key combination. So, in my tests, this solves the Crtl+C, Crtl+V and Crtl+S combinations.